# Запятая перед "И" в сложносочиненном предложении.

Tags: спп, пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

*У меня есть высшее образование и мне нравится читать.*

Так выглядит это предложение в профиле человека, претендующего на хорошее знание русского языка (блогер).

Некоторые выпускники филфака сказали, что при определенных логических связях запятая может не ставиться. Так ли это? Или правило с запятой железно выполняется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, когда обе части такого предложения имеют общий второстепенный член: Утром дул ветер и шел дождь. В приведенном Вами предложении нет общего второстепенного члена, поэтому запятая нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Я задал этот вопрос Грамме.ру. Вот ответ. "Запятая в данном случае необходима. При снятии запятых между частями сложносочиненного предложений учитывается не только семантический, но и формальный критерий (структурное сходство). Приведенное Вами предложение не подходит ни под один из случаев, приводимых в справочниках (Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М., 2009. С. 248-249; Розенталь Д.Э. Справочник по пунктуации. М., 1984. С. 140-141).
Несмотря на справедливо отмечаемую Вами семантическую близость частей этого сложноподчиненного предложения, первая часть является двусоставным предложением ("есть образование"), вторая - односоставным безличным предложением ("нравится читать").